# What is the server side javascript equivilant to xpath for xquery

Tags: javascript, xpath, xquery, marklogic

Given a collection like this:

```
collection : [
    'doc1.json' : {
       someXPath : [
           { expression : 'a' },
           { expression : 'b' },
           { expression : 'c' },
       ],
       otherLargeObject : [ ... ]
    },
    'doc2.json' : {...},
    'doc3.json' : {...}
]
```

Using **Xquery** I can select child nodes of the collection as follows:

```
fn:doc()//someXPath/expression/text()
```

resulting in something this:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', ... ]
```

The above syntax is concise and the result only includes the data I want.

Using **Javascript** I would try the following:

```
var results = [];
for (var doc of fn:doc()) {
    if (doc.someXPath) {
        results.push(doc.someXPath.map(function (x) {
            return x.expression;
        })
    }
}
```

The javascript code is verbose and not as versatile. The xquery example matches other document structures with different levels of nesting without the need for extra conditions.

Does the *doc* iterator retrieve the entire document in memory or just the parts that are accessed? e.g. is otherLargeObject loaded into memory in the javascript version? Is the javascript version as efficient as the xquery version?

Is something like the following possible?

```
var result = [];
for (var justTheNodesIWant in fn:doc()('//someXPath/expression/text()') {
    result.concat(justTheNodesIWant);
}
result;  // ['a', 'b', 'c', ... ]
```

Is there an equivalent way to achieve the xquery result and performace using server side javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below will work:

```
var results = [];

for (var exp of  xdmp.xqueryEval('fn:doc()/someXPath/expression')) {
  results.push(exp);
}

results
```

The downside of that is the mixing of languages, including embedding code in a string.

Comment: Plus need for an extra xdmp:eval execute privilege, and the potential security risks. You could also use `xpath()` on the Nodes in SJS, but that runs per doc. The above would be more efficient..

Comment: Thanks, that's neat. Can you tell me if the javascript snippet above has lower performance than the xquery?

Comment: From what I know, I'd expect performance to be equivalent (the bulk of the work is still being done in XQuery). If someone knows better, or if you find out something different, please let me know.